# Is there any operator in c which avoids any change in value of variable after the first assignment?

Tags: c

In this code once `f` is assigned some value of `i`, for example from inside the loop after 3 iterations `f=i=2`, then next time `f` cannot be assigned the value again: the value of `f` has to be rock solid to first assignment only.

```
    for(i=0;i<N-1;i++)
       {
        if(array[i+1]>array[i]);
        else if(array[i+1]<array[i])
        {
         f=i;s=i+1;}
        else
         {f=i;
         s=i+1;}
       }
```

Once `f` is initialized to one value of `i` it should not change. Is there any operator in C which helps? I thought of `static` but it's absolutely the wrong choice.

Comment: That's not what operators are meant for.

Comment: Why not qualify the variable `const`? That's exactly what you ask for.

Comment: Hello Olaf, I tried using const, compiler shows "14.singleswapsort.c:30:7: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘f’  f=i; "...that's violation of const declaration

Comment: You wrote in your title you want to prevent modification after **initialisation**. That is no constraint violation for `const` qualified variables. Of course you cannot assign a value to them; tht's exactly the idea! You seem to confuse assignment and initialisation.

Comment: That is nothing you can do in C resonably. If you need this for some reason, use a different language. Otherwise just write clear code. A function should never be that complicated that you cannot avoid unwanted modifications.

Comment: Thank you for the idea Mr Olaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `f` equal to some placeholder value initially.  Then, check for this placeholder and only make an assignment once:

```
int f = -1;
for (i=0; i < N-1; i++)
{
    if (array[i+1] > array[i]);
    else if (array[i+1] < array[i])
    {
        if (f == -1) f = i;
        s = i+1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (f == -1) f = i;
        s = i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you consider `min` to be an operator, then using  `INT_MAX` as the sentinel value would be pretty close to a "yes" answer.

Comment: That would not prevent assignment. If the test-code is forgotten, the variable still can be set. That makes the code bloated without a significant benefit. C is not the language for such requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no way to do what you want in C.  You cannot set a variable to any value and then prevent it from being set again in the future.  The best you can do is to set it some some value you do not plan to use normally, like -1 or something, then check to see if it equals that before you set it.  But you cannot prevent it from being set by some operator.